# assigning a variable value based on other variable in R

Tags: r, variable-assignment, subset

I have a data frame, that looks like this

```
   site trap.number  species dist.to.forest
1    1        5850                      NA
2    1        4851 bridelia              0
3    1        4852                      NA
4    1        4853                      NA
5    1        4854                      NA
6    1        4855                      NA
```

What I would like to do is fill in values for the variable dist.to.forest depending on the value of trap.number.  I can do this one at a time using

```
dat1$dist.to.forest[dat1$trap.number == 4851]<- 0
```

but there are many many traps that are 0 meters from the forest, and many many traps that are 10 meteres etc, so i would like to fill them all in quickly, i know the trap numbers and distances and i tried using this:

```
dat1$dist.to.forest[dat1$trap.number == c(4851, 4873, 4881, 4896, 4915)] <- 0
```

Although the actual list of trap numbers was much longer, i just shortened it here to fit on screen, but got an error about longer object not being a multiple of shorter object.

So I have two questions if anyone is kind enough to answer, the first, in my (limited) understanding of R, i thought the number 0 would get 'recycled' filling every row of dist.to.forest where the value of trap.number was the same as one of the values in the list i specified, but it doesnt and if anyone is kind explain why this is not the right way to think about it that would be great, and second can you tell me the code to do it correctly.  Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `%in%` instead of `==`.  While it's still a red message, that was a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, zero doesn't get recycled in this context because the thing you are assigning zero to could have at most length 1:

```
dat1$dist.to.forest[dat1$trap.number == c(4851, 4873, 4881, 4896, 4915)] <- 0
```

Is saying "assign 0 to `data1$dist.to.forest` when `dat1$trap.number` equals the vector `c(4851, 4873, 4881, 4896, 4915)`. Since `dat1$trap.number` has length 1, this never happens. If you did something like

```
dat1$dist.to.forest[dat1$trap.number == 4851] <- 0
```

Then the 0 would indeed be recycled, for each case where the condition in the square brackets is true, if any.

As pointed out in the comment of @RichardScriven, you can create a logical vector which determines if the `trap.number` takes any of the values `c(4851, 4873, 4881, 4896, 4915)`

```
dat1$dist.to.forest[dat1$trap.number %in% c(4851, 4873, 4881, 4896, 4915)] <- 0
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks this explains it excellently and i understand now the error in my thinking and code.  Much appreciated. Cheers!